# Cross Referencing Date Ranges for mulitple Entries

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I'm using Codeigniter to build an app and running into the following issue:

The app allows users to input multiple date ranges, each having a start and end date, i.e. 06-10-2011 to 06-14-2011.

I want to cross reference those date ranges to find a date range that exists for at least two users. The problem is that they don't need the strict start or end dates.

Basically, if each user input 1 date range similar to:

user1 : 06/10/2011 - 06/15/2011
user2 : 06/11/2011 - 06/14/2011
user3 : 06/12/2011 - 06/16/2011

Then the result would be:

common: 06/12/2011 - 06/14/2011

Any help would be great! P.s. I'm using Codeigniter with OverZealous Datamapper.

Answer (score 0):

when we can make the assumption that you are not referencing to *long* ranges you could itterate the days for each range, and use the dates as keys to a hashtable. that hashtable stores hashsets (or a list if you are sure that a user can not have overlapping ranges) of users. if the date is not in the table, create a new set for this date, and insert (append) the user that is associated to the current time range. if the date is in the table, just insert (append) the user ...

after all ranges have been processed, itterate the entires of the table and compare your total number of users to the length of the hashset (or list)